# leave that behavior in the background

Tags: meaning-in-context

Explain please the meaning of this phrase in the title. Macroeconomic models do not deal with the optimizing behavior but leave them in the background. I don't understand.

The source is the book "Macroeconomics" by Gregory Mankiw.
The context:

Yet the model does not focus on how these microeconomic decisions are made; instead, it leaves these decisions in the background. Similarly, although microeconomic decisions
underlie macroeconomic phenomena, macroeconomic models do not necessarily focus on the optimizing behavior of households and firms, but instead sometimes leave that behavior in the background.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From the context, it simply means that the models don't focus on/highlight/ deal with this optimizing behavior.